# Creating a array of custom objects from JSON, sent using PHP from a MySQL database

Tags: json, swift, ios

I'm using PHP to send data in JSON to create an array of custom objects in Swift. I've been told `retrieveData()` is bad code because it's in an infinite loop. I'm not sure on how to clean it up so it can be more efficient. On a side note, is there a way I can save the custom objects in an array that is easier to save to `UserDefaults` without NSCoder?

The app is basically a blog reader. It gets data from a server's database and displays it in a tableview.

MainController.swift

```
var jsonArray: NSMutableArray = []
var mainArray = [Blog]()

// Retrieving Data from Server
func retrieveData() {

    let getDataURL = "http://example.com/receiving.php"
    let url: NSURL = NSURL(string: getDataURL)!

    do {
        let data: Data = try Data(contentsOf: url as URL)
        jsonArray = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers) as! NSMutableArray

        // Looping through jsonArray
        for i in 0..<jsonArray.count {

        // Create Blog Object
        guard let bID: String = (jsonArray[i] as AnyObject).object(forKey: "id") as? String,
            let bName: String = (jsonArray[i] as AnyObject).object(forKey: "blogName") as? String,
            let bStatus1: String = (jsonArray[i] as AnyObject).object(forKey: "blogStatus1") as? String,
            let bStatus2: String = (jsonArray[i] as AnyObject).object(forKey: "blogStatus2") as? String,
            let bURL: String = (jsonArray[i] as AnyObject).object(forKey: "blogURL") as? String,
            let bType: String = (jsonArray[i] as AnyObject).object(forKey: "blogType") as? String,
            let bDate: String = (jsonArray[i] as AnyObject).object(forKey: "blogDate") as? String,
            let bPop: String = (jsonArray[i] as AnyObject).object(forKey: "blogPop") as? String

            else {
                print("Error: (Creating Game Object)")
                return
            }

            // Add Blog Objects to mainArray
            mainArray.append(Blog(blogName: bName, andBlogStatus1: bStatus1, andBlogStatus2: bStatus2, andBlogURL: bURL, andBlogID: bID, andBlogType: bType, andBlogDate: bDate, andBlogPop: bPop))
        }
    }
    catch {
        print("Error: (Retrieving Data)")
    }
    myTableView.reloadData()
}
```

Blog.swift - Handles the `Blog` custom objects that it gets from `retrieveData`

```
import UIKit

class Blog: NSObject {

// Strings
var blogName: String
var blogStatus1: String
var blogStatus2: String
var blogURL: String
var blogID: String
var blogType: String
var blogDate: String
var blogPop: String

// Converting Strings into Objects
init(blogName bName: String,
     andBlogStatus1 bStatus1: String,
     andBlogStatus2 bStatus2: String,
     andBlogURL bURL: String,
     andBlogID bID: String,
     andBlogType bType: String,
     andBlogDate bDate: String,
     andBlogPop bPop: String)
{
    self.blogName = bName
    self.blogStatus1 = bStatus1
    self.blogStatus2 = bStatus2
    self.blogURL = bURL
    self.blogID = bID
    self.blogType = bType
    self.blogDate = bDate
    self.blogPop = bPop
    super.init()
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me try to clean it little bit.

1 First of all you made `jsonArray` global. I think it's not necessary.
You can declare it locally where needed.

2 `retrieveData()` function looks very messy.
You can abstract that creation of `Blog` object.

3 You can improve `for` loop code

So here is what I would propose:

```
class Blog: NSObject {

  var blogName: String!
  var blogStatus1: String!
  var blogStatus2: String!
  var blogURL: String!
  var blogID: String!
  var blogType: String!
  var blogDate: String!
  var blogPop: String!

  init?(from jsonObject: AnyObject) {
    guard let bID: String = jsonObject.object(forKey: "id") as? String,
        let bName: String = jsonObject.object(forKey: "blogName") as? String,
        let bStatus1: String = jsonObject.object(forKey: "blogStatus1") as? String,
        let bStatus2: String = jsonObject.object(forKey: "blogStatus2") as? String,
        let bURL: String = jsonObject.object(forKey: "blogURL") as? String,
        let bType: String = jsonObject.object(forKey: "blogType") as? String,
        let bDate: String = jsonObject.object(forKey: "blogDate") as? String,
        let bPop: String = jsonObject.object(forKey: "blogPop") as? String else {
            print("Error: (Creating Game Object)")
            return nil
    }
    blogName = bName
    blogStatus1 = bStatus1
    blogStatus2 = bStatus2
    blogURL = bURL
    blogID = bID
    blogType = bType
    blogDate = bDate
    blogPop = bPop
    super.init()
  }
}
```

So outside world will not have to worry about converting `json` object into `Blog`.

Then simply use this abstraction as:

```
var mainArray = [Blog]()

func retrieveData() {

  let getDataURL = "http://example.com/receiving.php"
  let url: NSURL = NSURL(string: getDataURL)!

  do {
    let data: Data = try Data(contentsOf: url as URL)
    let jsonArray = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers) as! NSMutableArray

    // Looping through jsonArray
    for jsonObject in jsonArray {
      if let blog = Blog(from: jsonObject as AnyObject) {
        mainArray.append(blog)
      }
    }
  }
  catch {
    print("Error: (Retrieving Data)")
  }
  myTableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: I would make it a failable initializer: `init?(from jsonObject: AnyObject)` .

Comment: Yes, would be more cleaner way; I forgot this approach, I'll mention it

Comment: A) I would retrieveData should only return an array of `Blog`. In an other method I would call this and set then thel mainArray with the result and reload data. If you change your source then you can easy exchange the call to retrieveData

Comment: B) mainData is not set to empty before filling it up